# Отображение содержимого docx файла и переход по ссылке

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, rtf, docx

[image: Вывод в RichTextBox]

Как сделать так что бы ссылки отображались так же как и в ворде и был возможен переход по ним? Результат на скрине аналогичный с docx и rtf.
Думал использовать html файлы и webbrouser, но слишком уж много файлов придется конвертировать.

Comment: А как вы отображаете сейчас?

Comment: Результат на скрине. Использую RichTextBox.LoadFile для rtf и Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word для docx. Просто все вот эти ссылки между знаками <> не должны показываться. Я бы хотел, что бы они отображались как в ворде и можно было бы переходить по ним.

Comment: Чтобы можно было переходить по ссылкам, сделайте [как в документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.linkclicked(v=vs.110).aspx): подпишитесь на `LinkClicked` и вызывайте `Process.Start`.

Comment: По поводу отображения, тут всё хуже. Вот [этот тред](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1d75564c-537a-4de0-90df-5ee97b3adffb/hyperlink-formatting-issue-in-richtextbox?forum=winforms) говорит, что отображение _без_ текста ссылки — фича Ворда, так что возможно вам придётся пробегаться по тексту создавать кастомные ссылки наподобие [этого подхода](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox). Насколько мне помнится, в WPF такой проблемы нет, так что...